# Process For Invalid Edit Approvals

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I've had a couple of cases lately where there were edits made by users that required approval.

In both of these cases, I felt that the edit should definitely not have been approved.  In one case, the edit itself was damaging to the intent of the question, and in the other it added no value.

Although I personally rejected the edits, two other users approved them and they were accepted.

In the case of the damaging edit, I reversed it immediately but left the other (I could have been harsh\wrong and it didn't affect the meaning of the techincal question itself).

**What is the correct approach in situations such as these?**

- Is it acceptable for me to reverse the edit even though two others approved it?
- I felt like I wanted to flag the two approvers for accepting an edit that clearly damaged the post. Is this appropriate, and is there an option to do this?

I apologise that I do not have references to the edits.  Please consider that the question is more about the correct procedure to follow as opposed to specific edits.

Comment: Without the links to the posts, this is actually harder to comment on. As result this is a broader opinion and not specific to the scenarios you've seen. If they (the edits) were strictly damaging, I would rollback the edit, and then raise a custom flag on the question to alert a moderator of whomever accepted the edit in the queue. if they simply lowered the quality, I would likely rollback it too, using the edit function so i can give a reason and likely include my own "improvements". I would be less likely to raise a custom flag in that scenario.

Comment: If you *don't* revert the edits, a mod can override the result of the review which will take away the +2 rep from the suggester(s) as well

Comment: @NickA True, but a harmful edit could be damaging for the OP in the meantime. A mod can always hand out a manual ban if necessary.

Comment: I'm thinking predominantly related to edits when the editor has mistakenly changed the technical meaning of the question (perhaps due to a lack of understanding of the language) as opposed to deliberate vandalism. In these cases, I'm labouring under the assumption that the 'approvers' should have taken the time to verify that the technical aspects of the question didn't change in the edit.